# magento dont translate countries name dropdown in checkout page

Tags: php, magento

I have japanese, chinese, and some other non latin text store views. in checkout page, I dont want to translate countries name that shown in dropdown input. I have no idea how to do that, I already look into

```
lib/Zend/Locale/Data/Translation.php
```

somebody told me to look at that file, but i have no idea about this file. How to prevent magento to automatically translate those names?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the allowed countries by the following code without translation

```
<?php $_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->loadData()?>


<select name="country" id="country">

<option value="">-- Please Select --</option>

<?php foreach($_countries as $_country): ?>

<option value="<?php echo $_country->get value() ?>">

<?php echo $_country->getLabel()?>

</option>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```

Comment: thanks, but it still translated. please check this debug result http://pastebin.com/7nDhuqga